# What is the formula for E[Y|X=x] if you already have fx(x) and f(x,y)?

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation

I just need the formula.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: $E(Y|X=x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{yf(x,y)}{f_{X}(x)}dy$

Answer (score 2):

The conditional density $f(y\mid x) = f(x,y)/f(x)$.

Then $\Bbb E[Y\mid X=x] = \int_\Bbb R y\,f(y\mid x)\,\mathrm dy$